# How can I rotate a vector (centripetal force)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I'm trying to implement centripetal force in a programming language.

I saw some videos teaching the theory. But I dont know how to apply that in a programming language.

If I understand I have to apply centripetal force `ac = v²/r` to the velocity vector. But I dont know exactly how to proceed.

I have two game objects, one depicting Earth, other depicting Moon. What I wanted is to translate the moon around earth and using a button to "cut/cancel" the centripetal force in order to the moon get out to the earth's orbit.

I have no clue how to start that.

All I know is to rotate like this:

```
velocity.x = Mathf.Cos(Time.time) * earth_moon_radius;
velocity.z = Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * earth_moon_radius;
moon.transform.position = velocity;
```

But how to apply centripetal force as described above?

Comment: Why rotate? Isnt rotation product of the force? If you want to apply the force I would stop rotating and keep only position vector and direction vector - each step add to position vector a multiple of direction vector(depending on speed) and apply the force to it(add multiple of center direction vector?). Its product should be identical to the rotation. EDIT: what object you want to apply the force on?

Comment: @wondra I'm probably messing everything. Can you show some code how to do that? Im noob. I want to apply the force to the Moon. It will rotate around the Earth.

Comment: Have you tried good old fashioned mass and gravity on the moon and earth?

Comment: @Fabricio I am just pointing out the moon should have one a speed vector in straight direction - if no force affect it, it would fly away from your map in straight line(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion). If you add the centripetal force(gravitation, or whatever pulling it to the earth), the straight vector will be adjusted dT (every little bit of time turns it a bit towards earth) and the result of the forces is your rotation. I am no physicist, so I might be wrong.

Comment: For this question, do you really want to do a simulation of the dynamics, using applied forces to calculate accelerations, velocities, and positions, **OR** do you just want an object that moves in a circle and then a straight line?  The simulation will give the same result, but it's significantly harder, so if you just want to motion, just do the motion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have the moon rotating around earth and some trigger to release the moon, it's easier to use rotation around a center instead of forces. Given the following GameObject hierarchy:

*Center* (`MoonRotator` attached)
-- *Moon*
-- *Earth*

```
public class MoonRotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool cancelCentripetalForce = false;
    public Vector3 angularVelocity = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 100f);

    public GameObject moon;

    void Update () {
        if (cancelCentripetalForce) {
            Vector3 radius = moon.transform.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 angularVelocityRadians = Mathf.Deg2Rad * angularVelocity;
            moon.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.Cross (angularVelocityRadians, radius);
            moon.transform.parent = null;
            Destroy (this);
        } else {
            Vector3 rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles + angularVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rot);
        }
    }
}
```

If `cancelCentripetalForce` is set true *Moon* stops travelling around earth but proceeds with its current tangential velocity. This is given as:
v = ω × r

*Earth* has `localPosition` (0, 0, 0) and *Moon* is in this example located in the x-y plane rotating around the z axis.

Comment: hi, i tried to implement this but my moon just stops moving after cancelCentripetalForce is pressed (in my script, it's changed to true after 3 seconds) - do you mind helping me or editing the script so that it keeps moving in the tangential velocity given by the cross product?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the force, add an opposing force vector that is based on your object's linear velocity and current direction.

So I have an object pointing straight along the Z axis. The object's 'forward' vector is 0, 0, 1. Do 1 - Math.abs(forward.x), same for y and z to get 1, 1, 0 when you're pointing forward along the Z axis. You want the direction you're pointing in to be 0'd so that the inertia from that direction is not damped in any way. Now you can apply a cancellation force in any direction that you are NOT pointed in.

This means that if your object is moving in any direction in world space that it's not facing in you can easily apply a cancellation force that is multiplied by the object's linear velocity to get circular motion that uses forces instead of directly setting velocity.

Another way you can do it is solve for V by manually setting it, then find radius using V=RW. You should know V and R or W. Now you can find the force necessary to keep the orbit stable around a point, rather than adding inertia from every frame.